# where can I find 'Application ID' in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, augmented-reality

I am configuring metaio SDK. Within the installation instructions it says:

```
'Log-in in the portal and add you **Application ID** and name to generate the new 
signature, then copy and paste your string instead of old one #define SDK_LICENSE 
"RfIXXL7+zVARfh98zMNuiQL1mCaRjUhCBXQxtsETPdM=" in MetaioSDKViewController.mm'
```

Where can I find my **Application ID**?

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode uses the bundle identifier found in the target's Info.plist file for code signing.

Which Info.plist file is selected is actually a build setting (normally in the target), and is usually set up by Xcode correctly. If you manually edited the Info.plist's bundle identifier value to your identifier, Xcode should use this identifier and code signing should work.

The default Info.plist file contains a bundle identifier that contains Xcode build settings and is processed to the final identifier when building the target.

Comment: I can see 'InfoPlist.strings' file and there is just this text there:
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */

Answer (score 0):

I assume its asking for the Application ID for the application you are developing.  That should be from iTunes Connect where you setup your application.  Once you create the application, their is a link with an ID for the application in the URL.

Comment: yes it's asking for the Application ID for the application I am  developing and its name.
how can I find it in iTunes?
I dont use iTunes for programming and I didn't connect it to my xcode
(maybe I didnt understand you well I am pretty beginner)